# Automatic double quotes,parenthesis etc. with Brackets editor

Tags: css, editor, parentheses, adobe-brackets

I'm using the "Brackets" from Adobe as my main web design code editor. The problem i have is when i want to type two quotes or parentheses etc. In sublime for example i just have to press only the left parentheses and it will automatically type the right one for me and put the cursor in the middle.

But in "Brackets" i have to type the left and the right and then manually with my arrow keys put the cursor in the middle. I have installed lots of extensions but with no luck. Is there any solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check off *Edit > Auto Close Braces* in the menu.